# the identifier "velocity" isn't declared in the current scope

Tags: godot, gdscript

"the identifier "velocity" isn't declared in the current scope."

godot is showing this error in  my code:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

func _physics_process(delta):
       if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
          velocity.x += 4 
       elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
          velocity.x += -4
```

*for some reason, I can't find the reason why this happens
pls answer*

*maybe the problem is with my code as I am purely a beginner and i am using godot version-3.4.2*

Comment: Godot claims `velocity` is not declared. You claim Godot is wrong on that regard. Well, where did you declare `velocity`? - I suspect you want to handle the `KinematicBody2D` as a `RigidBody2D` (which has a property `linear_velocity`). Are trying to translate code from another engine? I suggest to start with a Godot dedicated tutorial.

Comment: @Theraot thanks you for your response, i actually saw this code from a youtube tutorial and i just started with godot so this code

```if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
          velocity.x += 4 ```

was meant to move the ```kinematicbody2d``` when right key is pressed
and godot is my first engine soo

Comment: You move the `KinematicBody2D` by calling `move_and_slide`, which takes a velocity as fist parameter. I would expect `velocity` to be declared as a variable, and then passed to `move_and_slide`. Something like this: https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/2d/2d_movement.html#doc-2d-movement - I suppose they do something similar in the video.

Comment: thanks you so much for your help 
edit: yes, it solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

For reference, in case anyone else finds this now. If you're hitting this, you may be using an older version of godot (like LTS 3.5.2), and following a 4.x tutorial. I assume that's the case with OP, with the strange complication that it looks like the 4.0 beta wasn't out yet.

In godot 4.x, the standard way is now to set a built-in variable `velocity`, and then call move_and_slide without arguments.

https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/getting_started/first_3d_game/03.player_movement_code.html#testing-our-player-s-movement

```
extends CharacterBody3D

# How fast the player moves in meters per second.
@export var speed = 14
# The downward acceleration when in the air, in meters per second squared.
@export var fall_acceleration = 75

var target_velocity = Vector3.ZERO


func _physics_process(delta):
    var direction = Vector3.ZERO

    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_right"):
        direction.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_left"):
        direction.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_back"):
        direction.z += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed("move_forward"):
        direction.z -= 1

    if direction != Vector3.ZERO:
        direction = direction.normalized()
        $Pivot.look_at(position + direction, Vector3.UP)

    # Ground Velocity
    target_velocity.x = direction.x * speed
    target_velocity.z = direction.z * speed

    # Vertical Velocity
    if not is_on_floor(): # If in the air, fall towards the floor.
        target_velocity.y = target_velocity.y - (fall_acceleration * delta)

    # Moving the Character
    velocity = target_velocity
    move_and_slide()
```